# modular automorphism group for a faithful normal state restricted to a von Neumann subalgebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a Von Neumann algebra and $N$ be a von Neumann a subalgebra of $M$. Suppose there exists a normal faithful normal State $\phi$ on $M$, then we have the modular automorphism group $(\sigma_t^{\phi})_{t\in \Bbb R}$.

Since $\phi|_N$ is a normal faithful normal state on $N$, we have the modular automorphism group $(\sigma_t^{\phi|_N})_{t\in \Bbb R}$, where $\sigma_t^{\phi|_N}:N\rightarrow N$ is the $*$-automorphism.

What is the relationship between $\sigma_t^{\phi|_N}$ and $\sigma_t^{\phi}$.Does the following conclusion hold:

$\forall x\in N$, $\sigma_t^{\phi}(x)=\sigma_t^{\phi|_N}(x), t\in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equal, provided that $\sigma_t^\phi$ leaves $N$ invariant.

Given a weight, its modular group can be characterized as the unique one-parameter automorphism group of the algebra that commutes with the weight and satisfies the KMS condition. This is proven for instance in Theorem VIII.1.2 in Takesaki's *Theory of Operator Algebras 2*.

Comment: They are only equal if $\sigma^\phi$ leaves $N$ invariant. But this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Tiny detail I missed ;)